# How to register WebView as HTML Reader in Android?

Tags: android

My WebView application loads a html file and display it. Now how do I register it as a default HTML Reader in the Android system?

Meaning for example now if I click on an html attachment in email it shows "Complete Action using", then lists the HTML Readers in the Android system. How do I register my application to be one of them listed?

Must I modify my code to allow this? Currently my application is just loading a html attachment from the sdcard.

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Comment: You can't register views, you have to register classes. You'll have to register your activity with an intent filter with the correct values (which someone will surely post). You'll have to change your code to accept data that's passed in the intent.

Comment: Hi, How do I register the activity with an Intent filter? First I will need to specify in AndroidManifest.xml, then will it be automatically registered? Not sure of the different attributes that need to be specified within the Intent Filter in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
<activity android:name=".YourBrowserActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

Replace `YourBrowserActivity` with the name of your activity class. Call `getData()` on `getIntent()` to receive the URL or the requested page.

This will not replace the browser, however. If you tap on the earth symbol on the bottom of the home screen, this will not open your browser.

Comment: Right, with this you are telling to the system that you can handle http scheme, so if from an app a link is launched, your app will appear in the list of apps that can do something with that link.